# Can adding a towel to my swimtrunks make it dry faster?

Tags: thermodynamics

Could it be cost (perhaps energy or time) effective to throw a towel into the dryer with a collection of wet clothes?

> My thoughts in favor of an affirmative answer:

[This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/72760/would-a-small-puddle-of-water-evaporate-faster-if-you-spread-a-dry-towel-over-it) seems to support the answer that there are conditions which might make it the case that throwing a towel in a dryer might help. At least, it supports this thought if the dryer is broken. In this case it seems that a towel will help a spill dry faster.

> My thoughts in favor of a negative answer:

The amount of energy required to heat the water to evaporation could be independent of the mass which we are trying to heat. Or worse yet, it could be that the towel consumes some of the heat the dryer and impedes the process.

> My thoughts on something in between an affirmative and negative answer:

It could be that what we presume is sufficiently dry is relative to "If I put in my closet will it mold or smell bad?" In this case, it might be that throwing a towel might distribute the water into the towel which can consume enough water for us to say: "this is dry enough" somewhat faster.

What can physics contribute to this question? Thanks for any help!

Comment: It seems like you've already covered the three big factors in your question, but I'm not sure if there's really more of an "objective" answer.  The towel will likely help for the reasons stated in your first one, improving the heat/vapour transfer.  The towel will also act as a thermal sink, taking some of the heat supplied; leading to less heat going to the other clothes (assuming the drier doesn't vary the heating based on a sensed weight or something).  I think point 3 is also something to consider; but that's more human experience than physics.

Comment: @JMac Great. Thanks. I am not much of a physicist so it's helpful to have this confirmation.

Comment: *It could be that what we presume is sufficiently dry is relative to "If I put in my closet will it mold or smell bad?"* In chemistry we use the concept of *'dried to constant weight'*. It could be used here too as an objective definition of *'sufficiently dry'*.

Comment: Thanks Gert. Let me see if I can understand this: If you dry a towel it should (something like) asymptotically approach some constant weight and we can call this weight (or perhaps when we are within epsilon of this weight) it's 'dried to constant weight.'
Hopefully this is the right interpretation. 
Using this as our standard it seems more likely to me that we arrive at a negative answer to my question. Now we want to ask how long will it have to be in the dryer to hit a certain weight.

Comment: It seems to me that this is the perfect question to pose not to us nerds here at the interwebs but to nature itself. Just do the experiment of drying your trunks once with and once without a towel, while keeping everything else equal :)